ODEs with parameter and continuous/smooth dependence on initial conditions and parameter
For the purposes of differential geometry I would like to fully process the basics of ODEs, namely the existence/uniqueness theorem (EUT) and continuous/smooth dependence on initial conditions and parameters (CSD), in maximum generality. Many standard ODE textbooks relegate the general EUT to the back (assuming they cover it at all, which isn't always) and focus on linear systems or explicit examples, and most don't even mention parameters or CSD.

Firstly, I'd like to clarify what the right definitions are, because almost every text has its own conventions: my current reference, Bröcker's "Analysis in mehreren Variablen", defines an ODE with parameter as a continuous function
$$f:I\times U\times V\to\Bbb R^n$$
with $I$ a non-empty open interval, $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ open, and $V\subset\Bbb R^k$ (nothing is stated about it, so I assume it's an arbitrary euclidean set), while a solution to parameter $v\in V$ and initial condition $(t_0,x_0)\in I\times U$ is a differentiable function $x:J\to U$ for $J\subset I$ a non-empty open interval such that $$x'(t)=f(t,x(t),v),\qquad x(t_0)=x_0.$$
Is this definition correct? The text goes on to say that in general $V$ may be an arbitrary metric space without it affecting anything, but then in the proof of the existence theorem it begins by saying that "after shrinking $I,U,V$ we may assume $f$ is bounded", which would require $V$ to be locally compact, thus ruling out many metric spaces (and euclidean sets). What is the correct framework here? How would one even formulate smooth dependence in the case of general metric spaces?
What is an adequate reference for a meticulous, non-handwavy proof of CSD? So far besides Bröcker (which has many typos and, possibly, inconsistencies) I only have Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" and Conlon's "Differentiable Manifolds". Both are fine, if a little complicated, but are there no alternatives? Also they don't cover equations with parameters (I know such equations can be reduced to autonomous ones, but I'd still like a general formulation). The result I'm looking for should be roughly of this shape:


If $f$ is $C^k$ for $k\geq0$, satisfying the Lipschitz condition in $x$ uniformly for $(t,v)$ (possibly locally), and $(t_0,x_0,v_0)$ is arbitrary, then there exists an open neighbourhood $(t_0,x_0,v_0)\in I_0\times U_0\times V_0$ and a $C^k$ function $\alpha:I_0\times U_0\times V_0\to\Bbb R^n$ such that for $(x,v)$ fixed $\alpha(t,x,v)$ is a solution of the equation with parameter $v$ and initial condition $(t_0,x)$. [Here I suppose we must assume $V$ is euclidean open to discuss differentiability of $\alpha$]


Henri Cartan’s Differential Calculus, Dieudonne Treatise on Analysis Vol I, Loomis and Sternberg Advanced Calculus.

@peek-a-boo thanks, I'll look into them.

Anyway, if $T,X,V$ are topological spaces and you’re taking continuous $(t,x,v)\mapsto f(t,x,v)$, then it’s immediate from the definition that for any point $(t_0,x_0,v_0)$ there is a product neighborhood on which $f$ is bounded. No assumptions on the topologies of the individual spaces. But once we stop merely discussing continuity we of course need to step up our hypotheses.

@peek-a-boo what, how is that clear for arbitrary spaces and continuous functions? Shouldn't that be a consequence of compactness and the maximum theorem?

In general if $g:X\to Y$ goes from a topological space to a metric space and is continuous, then it is locally bounded. Given any point $x_0\in X$, consider the preimage of any bounded open neighborhood of $g(x_0)$ (e.g the open ball of radius 1). The preimage is open by continuity, and on this neighborhood $g$ by definition maps into a bounded set. Similar reasoning if $X$ is replaced by a product; then by definition of product topology, we can restrict further to a product neighbourhood.

@peek-a-boo oh, that was silly. Thanks!
